# How do I capture stdout and simulate stdin in a Haskell Tasty test?

Tags: haskell, stdout, stdin, tasty

My impure functions are defined as follows:

```
module HangmanImpure (HangmanImpure.getLine, HangmanImpure.putStr, HangmanImpure.putStrLn, HangmanImpure.strlen) where

import qualified System.IO as Sys

getLine :: IO String
getLine = do x <- Sys.getChar
             if x == '\n' then
                 return []
             else
                do xs <- HangmanImpure.getLine
                   return (x:xs)

putStr :: String -> IO ()
putStr [] = return ()
putStr (x:xs) = do Sys.putChar x
                   HangmanImpure.putStr xs
```

I want to test these functions using Tasty, like e.g. so:

```
module TestHangmanImpure (scProps) where

import qualified Test.Tasty as T
import qualified Test.Tasty.SmallCheck as SC

import qualified HangmanImpure as HI (getLine, putStr, putStrLn, strlen)

scProps :: T.TestTree
scProps = T.testGroup "checked by SmallCheck"
    [
        SC.testProperty "getLine should return what is written to stdin" $
            "Placeholder to get the test to run" == "Placeholder to get the test to run" -- HI.getLine == IO "Hello" -- PLEASE, HELP ME WITH SOME CONTENT HERE

        , SC.testProperty "putStr should write to stdout what it gets in as an argument" $
            "Placeholder to get the test to run" == "Placeholder to get the test to run" -- HI.putStr "Nice day!" -- PLEASE, HELP ME WITH SOME CONTENT HERE
    ]
```

I would be very thankful if anybody could fill in the body in the two simple tests I have indicated.

EDIT:
I think [In haskell, how can I interact with stdin of an `IO ()`?][1] could lead me to a solution. I can get that solution to work on my Win10 with HSpec. So this question is *almost* a duplicate. But I cannot get it to work using Tasty.HUnit. My tentative code runs as follows:

```
module TestUtilImpure (scProps, qcProps, uTests, properties) where
    
import qualified Test.Tasty as T
import qualified Test.Tasty.HUnit as HU
    
import StdInStdOutUtil as IOU (captureStdout, provideStdin)
import UtilImpure as UI (getLine)
    
properties :: T.TestTree
properties = T.testGroup "TestUtilImpure tests" [
          uTests
        ]
    
uTests :: T.TestTree
uTests = T.testGroup "Checked by HUnit"
        [
            HU.testCase "UI.getLine reading from stdin should return what was provided" $ do
                let line = "Hello, echo!\n"
                let capturedIOString = IOU.captureStdout (provideStdin line echo)
                capturedString <- capturedIOString
                HU.assertBool "The String returned from UI.getLine differs from the one provided for StdIn" $ capturedString == line
        ]

echo :: IO ()
echo = UI.getLine >>= Prelude.putStrLn
```

(I have put the solution from  [1]: [In haskell, how can I interact with stdin of an `IO ()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76683594/in-haskell-how-can-i-interact-with-stdin-of-an-io/76684040#76684040) into its own file referred by

```
 import StdInStdOutUtil as IOU (captureStdout, provideStdin)
```

My test fails:

> The String returned from UI.getLine differs from the one provided for
> StdIn

I get the same error message whether I test Prelude.getLine or my own UI.getLine. So I guess that there's some syntax I have not understood using Tasty that fails.

Comment: I don't think is possible with any property testing library. Notice that the caller of `getLine` doesn't know a thing about `getLine` other than its type signature. In particular there is no way for the caller to know `getLine` uses `stdin`.  Even if you make it explicit (ex: `getLine :: StdIn -> IO String` for some user-defined type `StdIn`) I don't think there is any way to test the real `stdin` (an interactive shell), at most you'd be testing some pure function  `String -> String` lifted to `IO`. Also, `smallcheck` is obsolete up to its documentations, and your test would fail for `\n`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your logic. "...the caller of getLine doesn't know a thing about getLine other than its type signature...". That is correct, in the same way as in principle the Prelude System.IO's signature of its variation of getLine has the same signature: getLine :: IO String. But I, the programmer know that it reads stdin because I have read its documentation and I have used and tested it. In the same way, I know that HangmanImpure.getLine also reads from stdin because I (well, Graham Hutton...) have written it. Sorry if have misunderstood what you tried to explain to me :-)

Comment: P.S.: I suspect withResourceSource in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.11.2.3/docs/Test-Tasty.html#v:withResource and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450329/access-test-resources-within-haskell-tests might have something to do with a solution. I am still looking for help and/or an explanation. BTW, I don't understand why I was down-voted, it shouldn't unqualify to be a newbie? And I have tried to google a solution, but my brain with its current Haskell skills is just not able to put the pieces I find together.

Comment: I didn't downvote... SO can be a little bit agressive sometimes. Let me develop the quote "the caller of getLine doesn't know a thing about getLine". A common poperty test is `reverse (reverse xs) == xs` where `xs` is a list and `reverse :: [a] -> [a]`. When writting a property for `reverse`, the caller (the prop. testing library) knows that `reverse` needs some input `[a]` which is the first argument of the function `reverse`, so It can generate one randomly and test the given property. In your case `getLine` has no input, it is a raw `IO String`. continue..

Comment: You know the "input" is the stdin but that is opaque to the rest of the program, hence there is no way to generate a random input for it... Again, `getLine` has no inputs from a type perspective. I think `withResourceSource` is for other kind of tests, like golden test, etc... not for property-based testing

Comment: I had not quite got the reason to exist of SmallCheck. Its strength is, as I now understand, that random values may be provided automatically as test input by Tasty. (It is not nesessary, and that led me astray. I had picked up from somewhere an example showing a SmallCheck test case with no lambda random input.) But I see now that bringing in SmallCheck confuscates what I really want to ask about. So the question is simply how to pump out strings to stdin and read strings from stdout so that I can test my getLine and putStr functions regardless which of the Tasty tools I would have to use :-)

Comment: Notice that you want to test out-of-haskell values (stdin, stdout). Moreover, both `getLine` and `putStr` do modify in place the resources you want to test... How to do that? also, `getLine` blocks until `stdin` has something to process. How would you test that? including in other languages?

Comment: If the `unix` package is available on your OS, you might like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76684040/791604) describing how to use it for this. If that works for you, it would be good to close this as a duplicate, so do please write a comment either saying that it does work for you or why it doesn't.

Comment: @Ismor: Done it extensively in Java tests with no problems. Redirecting stdin and stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I am using *Test.Tasty.HIOUnit* to test IO functions.

At the moment, *HIOUnit* is only available as source code at https://github.com/JoergBrueggmann/tasty-hiounit.

A test spec with *HIOUnit* looks like this:

```
import qualified Test.Tasty as T

import qualified Test.Tasty.HIOUnit as HIOU


testGroup :: T.TestTree
testGroup =
    T.testGroup
        "module Test.Tasty.HIOUnit"
        [
            tgFib
        ]

tgFib :: T.TestTree
tgFib = 
    T.testGroup
        "Fib.ioFib"
        [
            -- edge cases using values arround zero
            HIOU.testCase "Fib.ioFib -2" (HIOU.IOTestParameter ( Just "-2" ) fdefFib ( Just "-1" ) ( Just "" ) ( Just 0 )), 
            HIOU.testCase "Fib.ioFib -1" (HIOU.IOTestParameter ( Just "-1" ) fdefFib ( Just "1" ) ( Just "" ) ( Just 0 )), 
            HIOU.testCase "Fib.ioFib 0" (HIOU.IOTestParameter ( Just "0" ) fdefFib ( Just "0" ) ( Just "" ) ( Just 0 )), 
            HIOU.testCase "Fib.ioFib 1" (HIOU.IOTestParameter ( Just "1" ) fdefFib ( Just "1" ) ( Just "" ) ( Just 0 )), 
            HIOU.testCase "Fib.ioFib 2" (HIOU.IOTestParameter ( Just "2" ) fdefFib ( Just "1" ) ( Just "" ) ( Just 0 )), 
            HIOU.testCase "Fib.ioFib 3" (HIOU.IOTestParameter ( Just "3" ) fdefFib ( Just "2" ) ( Just "" ) ( Just 0 ))
        ]

fdefFib :: HIOU.IOFunctionDefinition
fdefFib = 
    HIOU.IOFunctionDefinition
        "Fib"
        (Just "ioFib")
        [HIOU.sMultiLine|
import qualified System.IO as Sys


ioFib :: IO ()
ioFib = 
    do
        Sys.hSetBuffering Sys.stdout Sys.NoBuffering
        sNumber <- getLine
        let
            niNumber = (read sNumber) :: Integer
        putStr (show (fib niNumber))

fib :: (Integral n) => n -> n
fib n 
    | n >= 0 = fib' n (0,1)
    | even n = 0 - fib (-n)
    | otherwise = fib (-n)
  where
    fib' n' (a, b)
        | n'==0      = a
        | otherwise = fib' (n'-1) (b, a+b)
|]
```